# NFT Image not Displaying in Pool.pm after using the 721 Metadata Standard

Tags: nft, native-assets, metadata

I am not seeing the image of the NFT I minted a couple of hours ago on pool.pm.  I used the standard recommended by Alessandro Konrad and Smaug in https://github.com/Berry-Pool/CIPs/blob/master/CIP-NFTMetadataStandard.md.

The gif in question is 15mb and it displays perfectly in IPFS using the Brave browser and in the Blockfrost IPFS web gateway.

Here is the metadata file:

```
{
  "721": {
    "4a2ba87b606a0aeb40916e906670a346c4b915840a755ddf109af709": {
    "cardanollama001": {
    "name": "Cardano Llama 001",
    "image": "ipfs://QmSahUdK9RTNDBGEq6xHWHZXRFwyQv8wBAtRgpxFCkNvqz",
    "description": "1bit aestethic, 256 colors, 90 hand-glitched frame loop",
    "size": "1000x666",
    "rarity": "225 of 250"
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the link to the pool.pm link:

https://pool.pm/77a6f71a13e82794409d06c7486a59bb7a6af38e223b646c07e3262e.cardanollama001

I think I followed the standard to a tee, but I am stumped at this issue, and I can't figure out a solution.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem mate, do you found any solution rather than reducing the image size?

Comment: Hey [@Anis](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/users/4486/anis) If you give me the minting transaction hash I can try to help.

Answer (score 2):

The [metadata in your mint transaction](https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/8be04d6a8e22c40f2b3970b0be893b5757d0f237efba997346cb145ccc60b7b3?tab=metadata) looks good, it follows the standard correctly.

The only thing that kind of violates that standard is the size of your image (see chapter ["Structure")](https://github.com/Berry-Pool/CIPs/blob/master/CIP-NFTMetadataStandard.md#structure):

> The `image` and `name` property are marked as required. `image` should be an URI pointing to a resource with mime type `image/*` used as **thumbnail** or as actual link if the NFT is an image **(ideally <= 1MB)**.

I assume that the creator of pool.pm has set a limit for the size of the images to prevent long loading times of the website. So your 15MB image is probably just too big. Unfortunately the source code of pool.pm is not available, so I can't check if my guess is correct.

To fix this, you can upload a smaller version as `image` and the full resolution version of your image as `source`. Or you can try to optimize the size of the existing image.

> The `type` and `src` properties are optional. If `type` is defined, `src` will be an URI pointing to a resource of this mime type. If the mime type is `image/*`, `src` points to the same image in an higher resolution.

---

EDIT: Looking at the pool.pm page of your asset, it looks like the JSON metadata is not parsed correctly:

[image]

Usually, the properties should be shown like that:

[image]

This could be caused by the commas you used in the description property. So it's likely a bug on pool.pm. You could create an issue on their GitHub repo: https://github.com/SmaugPool/pool.pm/issues

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the minting transaction, there seems to be a mismatch between the policy ID in the minting transaction and the metadata policy ID field:

https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/8be04d6a8e22c40f2b3970b0be893b5757d0f237efba997346cb145ccc60b7b3?tab=tokenmint

Minting policy ID: `77a6f71a13e82794409d06c7486a59bb7a6af38e223b646c07e3262e`
Metadata policy ID: `4a2ba87b606a0aeb40916e906670a346c4b915840a755ddf109af709`