# Metadata '721' error on pool.pm

Tags: nft, minting, metadata

Hello and thank you beforehand for your time! I read a lot before posting and could not find a solution to this.
Pool.pm is complaining about the metadata '721' throwing an error: "Expecting an OBJECT with a field named `721`"

I first thought I made the transaction using a different policy id than the metadata like in this post: [NFT Image not Displaying in Pool.pm after using the 721 Metadata Standard](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/nft-image-not-displaying-in-pool-pm-after-using-the-721-metadata-standard)
But as you can see from https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/c02c4db6bc9b2b9f3adcac930559368f7c2a4f00a2a53fc8661fae3b5ce844b2?tab=metadata the policy id matches the one on the metadata. The metadata I used is:

```
{
  "777": {
    "prc": "0.5",
    "addr": [
      "addr1q8pfw723tpkt8hl7q4wxx7h9seqt4cy22zrqk4axmhmcglwykt772jcyu6u",
      "9pv84nktsmpefeh7w9y6hdr87a65a93ysut2t0r"
    ]
  },

  "721": {
    "3e3a9f39933d04bd854527801f615d35d1cbe1b0344d482af20343ae": {
      "ShaveandTattooed": {
        "Name": "Shave and Tattooed",
        "Artist": "Marvin Lunas",
        "Image": "QmRTJUU8MUw5rUzES6XJd5RiA55K9seVAWU3tTkS8UoQYi",
        "mediaType": "image/png",
        "Description": "Description",
        "files": [
          {
            "mediaType": "image/png",
            "src": "QmUhgW6c8MKmzZKMNtr8Sfvb8UjqM3bgCh6X1upDCNAgHH",
            "Name": "Shave and Tattooed"
          }
        ],
        "ID": "1",
        "Minting Platform": "https://adamagic.io"
      }
    },
    "Version": "1.0"
  }
}
```

I have no idea what is causing this issue because I did use the same template before and it was all good.
It also has a problem while loading the thumbnail and at this point, I think the problem is on me.

Once again, thank you all for your time and effort!
Cheers

Comment: When I tried I did not get a 721 error from pool.pm. The assets show correctly with the correct policy ID eg https://pool.pm/asset1xpdk028mq57te9dkg62rvy79nv2mhl4zr78xgn and https://pool.pm/asset1qlmcztdqq3w8fu5jfxrmsel40yn0y652hhs9ap . The policy shows ok https://pool.pm/policy/3e3a9f39933d04bd854527801f615d35d1cbe1b0344d482af20343ae . 
But the policy when searched shows 'no match found' using 
https://pool.pm/tokens/3e3a9f39933d04bd854527801f615d35d1cbe1b0344d482af20343ae - I think pool.pm only shows 'recent' minted or transferred NFTs as there are so many.

Answer (score 2):

It's showing up for me alright on pool.pm: https://pool.pm/asset1xpdk028mq57te9dkg62rvy79nv2mhl4zr78xgn

Might have been just a temporary issue while data was populating?

There's a testing tool here, that you can use to verify it works: https://pool.pm/test/metadata

Here it's populated with your metadata: [Link](https://pool.pm/test/metadata?metadata=%257B%2522721%2522%253A%257B%25223e3a9f39933d04bd854527801f615d35d1cbe1b0344d482af20343ae%2522%253A%257B%2522ShaveandTattooed%2522%253A%257B%2522Name%2522%253A%2522Shave%2520and%2520Tattooed%2522%252C%2522Artist%2522%253A%2522Marvin%2520Lunas%2522%252C%2522Image%2522%253A%2522QmRTJUU8MUw5rUzES6XJd5RiA55K9seVAWU3tTkS8UoQYi%2522%252C%2522mediaType%2522%253A%2522image%252Fpng%2522%252C%2522Description%2522%253A%2522Description%2522%252C%2522files%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522mediaType%2522%253A%2522image%252Fpng%2522%252C%2522src%2522%253A%2522QmUhgW6c8MKmzZKMNtr8Sfvb8UjqM3bgCh6X1upDCNAgHH%2522%252C%2522Name%2522%253A%2522Shave%2520and%2520Tattooed%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522ID%2522%253A%25221%2522%252C%2522Minting%2520Platform%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Fadamagic.io%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522Version%2522%253A%25221.0%2522%257D%252C%2522777%2522%253A%257B%2522prc%2522%253A%25220.5%2522%252C%2522addr%2522%253A%255B%2522addr1q8pfw723tpkt8hl7q4wxx7h9seqt4cy22zrqk4axmhmcglwykt772jcyu6u%2522%252C%25229pv84nktsmpefeh7w9y6hdr87a65a93ysut2t0r%2522%255D%257D%257D)

When you remove or rename the "721" object you'll see your exact error show up: *"Expecting an OBJECT with a field named `721`"*.

So if this is the place you're seeing it, there might be just a simple syntax error in the json you're putting in here.

Just some potential minor improvements to the metadata:

According to the spec at https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip25/#specification you should use lowercase attribute names like "name" and "image" instead of "Name" or "Image".

And for the image hashes I'd add "ipfs://" as a prefix to make it more clear where to look for them, but it does usually work fine without.

Anyways looks like it all works fine on my side as is